# How will I get Path?

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I am using the Glide to display images in my app. Now I want to know the location where the Glide is storing the cached images downloaded from the urls.

I am using below code to display image.

```
    Glide.with(context).load(str).
            diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
            .into(image1);
```

Comment: Please don't repeat questions. Simply editing your original post with any new information you have, or any new code you've tried, will bump it to the top of the active queue.

Comment: @MikeM. But I not found any soltuion? Why you duplicated? This is wrong

Comment: Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not the kind of site where you can just repost questions over and over again. As I mentioned above, simply editing your original question will bump it to the top of the active queue. Furthermore, this question is still in the exact same spot on the front page as it was, right now, and it points directly to where users can post answers, if they'd like to.

Comment: @MikeM. Can't you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619895/how-to-get-cached-image-path-which-is-stored-by-glide-in-android